# How to recover images from removed Imgur album?

Tags: imgur, data-recovery

I had an art album with 651 images in it, and when I went to open it this morning to add more photos, this message popped up:

[image]

I have tried refreshing the album multiple times on several different devices (phone, iPad, computer), but to no avail. If I cannot recover the album, how do I download all the images in the album? Even when I sort by images instead of by albums, they don’t show up.

Comment: When you click on the `Images` link  [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W3KM.png) does the album show up?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the album that has been deleted and not the images inside the album, it might be possible to download them using the Imgur API if you have the album URL.

You can use [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) to download an Imgur album. Just give [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) the URL to the album, and it will try to download it.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.  *"might be possible"*?  Answers should where possible be self-contained and include supporting information.  If the album URL no longer resolves, why would passing it to another app be more successful?  Please edit the answer to provide more details.